# Move data for matching string for a record to another column in the data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below. So if the string in column LOC is same for the record id then move the information from 2nd row to columns in the 1st row.

```
mydata
ID LOC LOC_a LOC_b LOC_2a LOC_2b
1 LAX 1 2
1 LAX 3 4
1 NJ 1 2
2 LAX 1 2
3 NJ 1 2
4 DM 5 6
4 DM 7 8

Desired output
ID LOC LOC_a LOC_b LOC_2a LOC_2b
1 LAX 1 2 3 4
1 NJ 1 2 
2 LAX 1 2
3 NJ 1 2
4 DM 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: This is called `widening/casting` the data. you cn use `tidyr::pivot_wider`  or `reshape2::dcast` etc

Comment: It looks like you have 4 columns but why are there 6 column names? `LOC_2a` and `LOC_2b` are all missing values? Could you provide reproducible data?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify exactly what your original data look like and make this a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = ID) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(LOC_a, LOC_b),
               names_vary = 'slowest')

# A tibble: 4 × 6
     ID LOC   LOC_a_1 LOC_b_1 LOC_a_2 LOC_b_2
  <int> <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1 LAX         1       2       3       4
2     2 LAX         1       2      NA      NA
3     3 NJ          1       2      NA      NA
4     4 DM          5       6       7       8
```

---

If you must have the names as presented, use `names_glue` to rewrite the current names to the needed names:

```
df %>%
 mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = ID) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(LOC_a, LOC_b),
             names_vary = 'slowest',
             names_glue = '{str_replace(.value, "(?<=_)", as.character(rn))}')

# A tibble: 4 × 6
     ID LOC   LOC_1a LOC_1b LOC_2a LOC_2b
  <int> <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1 LAX        1      2      3      4
2     2 LAX        1      2     NA     NA
3     3 NJ         1      2     NA     NA
4     4 DM         5      6      7      8
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively per the column names you are expecting

```r
df %>% mutate(row=row_number(), .by=c(ID, LOC)) %>% pivot_longer(-c(ID,LOC,row)) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('nam', 'val'), sep='_') %>% 
  mutate(name=ifelse(row>1, paste0(nam,'_',row,val), paste0(nam,'_',val))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, LOC), names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID LOC   LOC_a LOC_b LOC_2a LOC_2b
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 LAX       1     2      3      4
2     1 NJ        1     2     NA     NA
3     2 LAX       1     2     NA     NA
4     3 NJ        1     2     NA     NA
5     4 DM        5     6      7      8
```